# Generate Moodle exercises with images using the exams package

Tags: r, moodle, r-exams

I am using the `exams` package, I want to generate some Moodle exercises with it which incorporate some images. Although using this code in a `*rmd` file:

````
```{r, echo = FALSE, results = "hide"}
exams::include_supplement("ae1_2_1e2.png")
```
Question
========
Question text:

\centering
$\includegraphics[width=0.55 \textwidth] {ae1_2_1e2.png}$

Answerlist
----------
* answer a
* answer b
* answer c
* answer d


Solution
========


Answerlist
----------
* True
* False
* False
* False


Meta-information
================
exname: ae1_2_1
extype: schoice
exsolution: 1000
exshuffle: 4
````

Which produces this results in Moodle:

[image]

Another question is, does the package allows to use images as options in the Moddle exercises (i.e. schoice)? Example:

````
```{r, echo = FALSE, results = "hide", out.width = "20%"}
exams::include_supplement(c("ae4_3_2_1e2.png","ae4_3_2_3e4.png"))
```
Question
========
For a right-tailed test (using the Neyman-Pearson criteria), which would be the rejection region for a t-test (independent samples)?

Answerlist
----------
* \ ![](ae4_3_2_1e2.png) $\bigg]-\infty;-t_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2};(n_1+n_2-2)}\bigg] \cup \bigg[t_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2};(n_1+n_2-2)};+\infty\bigg[$.
* \ ![](ae4_3_2_1e2.png) $\bigg]-\infty;-t_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2};(n_1-n_2)}\bigg] \cup \bigg[t_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2};(n_1-n_2)};+\infty\bigg[$.
* \ ![](ae4_3_2_3e4.png) $\bigg[t_{1-\alpha;(n_1-n_2)};+\infty\bigg[$.
* \ ![](ae4_3_2_3e4.png) $\bigg[t_{1-\alpha;(n_1+n_2-2)};+\infty\bigg[$.
````

[image]

**SOLVED**

````
You cannot have the same image file in different options. If you want to use the same image, you have to produce a copy of it and use a different name.

So the new code:

```{r, echo = FALSE, results = "hide", out.width = "20%"}
exams::include_supplement(c("ae4_3_2_1.png","ae4_3_2_3.png","ae4_3_2_2.png","ae4_3_2_4.png"))
```
Question
========
For a right-tailed test (using the Neyman-Pearson criteria), which would be the rejection region for a t-test (independent samples)?

Answerlist
----------
* \ ![](ae4_3_2_1.png){width=20%} $\bigg]-\infty;-t_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2};(n_1+n_2-2)}\bigg] \cup \bigg[t_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2};(n_1+n_2-2)};+\infty\bigg[$.
* \ ![](ae4_3_2_2.png){width=20%} $\bigg]-\infty;-t_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2};(n_1-n_2)}\bigg] \cup \bigg[t_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2};(n_1-n_2)};+\infty\bigg[$.
* \ ![](ae4_3_2_3.png){width=20%} $\bigg[t_{1-\alpha;(n_1-n_2)};+\infty\bigg[$.
* \ ![](ae4_3_2_4.png){width=20%} $\bigg[t_{1-\alpha;(n_1+n_2-2)};+\infty\bigg[$.

Meta-information
================
exname: RTT
extype: schoice
exsolution: 0001
exshuffle: TRUE
````

And the result (thanks to @Achim):

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are using R/Markdown (.Rmd) exercises, then Markdown should be used for including static graphic files:

```
Question text:
\
![](ae1_2_1e2.png)
```

Inclusion of LaTeX is possible but only for mathematical equations - putting the `\includegraphics{}` into math mode is not appropriate here.

An example template that includes a static PNG file is available at: http://www.R-exams.org/templates/Rlogo/. Note that the backslash embeds the image in such a way that no caption is added here. See the `pandoc` documentation for more details: https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#images

Below is also a worked example (`mice.Rmd`) for images as answers in Moodle, restricting the width to the same value for all images:

````
```{r, include=FALSE}
download.file("https://i.pinimg.com/originals/f7/7b/17/f77b173fb104d07130697c9d3a024e75.png", "a.png")
download.file("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/f/fe/Speedy_Gonzales.svg/1200px-Speedy_Gonzales.svg.png", "b.png")
download.file("https://www.disneyclips.com/images3/images/basil-great-mouse-detective.png", "c.png")
```

Question
========
Which of these cartoon mice belongs to the Disney franchise?

Answerlist
----------
* ![](a.png){width=20%}
* ![](b.png){width=20%}
* ![](c.png){width=20%}

Meta-information
================
exname: Mice
extype: schoice
exsolution: 001
exshuffle: TRUE
````

In Moodle this is rendered in the following way:

[image: mice screenshot]

Comment: And the width argument would be?

Comment: Please see my edition to the initial question, I would like to add images as choice options.

Comment: Added now. Note, however, that it is not recommended to extend questions to other related questions after they have been answered. Better ask a more precise question initially or ask a new question later.

Comment: Thank you! The problem with the multiple images in the options list was different. I found it by chance... The problem was that you cannot use the same image in different options, even if the text next to each image is different...